# APNs Server for handling streams from PHP script

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I have a web server that sends push notifications to devices when certain actions are performed with a POST or GET. This works, but because of the nature of having to open an SSL connection to APNS, write all the tokens and exit, the actions that involve this operation are latent compared to those who do not. The latency is only a second or so, but a second is still significantly longer than say 100ms, which is how long it takes otherwise (if I comment out the APNS part).

It seems that it's also bad practice to open and close the connection to APNS every time you want to send notifications, not only because of the extra time it takes. I believe a better approach would be to have a different server (not running PHP) handle the stream writing to APNS and receive tokens and messages by let's say some kind of python service, perhaps.

Basically:

Web Server sends fwrite by php (unencrypted, no SSL) to a socket on a local server that has a persistent connection to APNS open, which also is asynchronous in its handling of the response from to the APNS operation: The problem is that PHP will wait until it has written all bytes to the socket before it echoes the desired response to the client. I would imagine it takes much less time to fwrite to a local server unencrypted than it does to SSL to APNS. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I don't have a lot of experience with Python, but as far as I know it's not that hard.

I have the tokens stored in MySQL and retrieving and generating the payload with PHP in place and working - it's just slowing everything down the way it's set up now.

I cannot find any guides on this subject - only how to do what I am already doing with fwrite and OpenSSL in PHP.

I seek suggestions as how to best handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to switch to Python to solve this issue. What you could do is tweak your design a bit to resemble more of "dump and purge" concept.

Basically, the scripts that receive the GET and POST calls dump the data related to the push notification payload locally.

In the background, you have a PHP script running all the time that has already established a connection with APNS and just checks constantly if anything has been dumped locally and needs to be sent.

**Script A (The dumper):**

```php
// ... something triggers a push ...
if ($_GET['something'] == 'foo') {
    $data = // Get all data needed to build push
    createPayload($data); // Dump data somewhere; file or database
}
// ... something else maybe ...
return; // Return asap to not keep client waiting
```

**Script B (The purger):**

```php
$apns = // Open connection to Apple Push server
while (TRUE) {
    // Read file or database where payloads get dumped
    $success = (fwrite(payload to $apns));
    sleep(5); // Sleep a bit to avoid CPU going crazy
    if (!$success) {
        // Reopen connection with Apple
    }
}
// Close apns here in case you have a break condition in your loop
```

Using two scripts instead of one, you will return to your client as quickly as possible and still be able to send push notification quickly to Apple's servers.

Comment: This is a good idea - but waiting 5 seconds in script the purger is not fast enough. It needs to relay instantly, which is why I considered the other approach. Also, constantly checking the hard drive for changes seems to no be a very good design. This is more of a "save and do it later"-approach, and while not useless it doesn't really solve the problem.

Right now I'm looking at doing it with Java instead.

Comment: In that case, you could have Script A write to Socket X which in turn is being listened to by Script B and will execute immediately.

Comment: Sure. For such a use-case, PHP will not be your bottle-neck; the network latency between your server and Apple will. So if you already have code that's working in PHP, you might as well re-use it. Your concern about PHP waiting to respond to client until it has written to socket is valid but the overhead of that should be negligible. If it isn't, you could introduce a middle-man script that Script A executes in the background so that it can return immediately without waiting for any response; but unnecessary IMO.

Comment: So something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create-listen.php in one script that just passes information on to APNS, perhaps.

Comment: Yep, that's the idea.